Генерация QR в модели Django
У меня есть модель Django. В которой нужно генерировать QR-код(qr_code) в соответствии с атрибутом name.
class Book(models.Model):




YEAR_CHOICES = [(1930, 1930), (1931, 1931), (1932, 1932), (1933, 1933), (1934, 1934), (1935, 1935), (1936, 1936), (1937, 1937), (1938, 1938), (1939, 1939), (1940, 1940), (1941, 1941), (1942, 1942), (1943, 1943), (1944, 1944), (1945, 1945), (1946, 1946), (1947, 1947), (1948, 1948), (1949, 1949), (1950, 1950), (1951, 1951), (1952, 1952), (1953, 1953), (1954, 1954), (1955, 1955), (1956, 1956), (1957, 1957), (1958, 1958), (1959, 1959), (1960, 1960), (1961, 1961), (1962, 1962), (1963, 1963), (1964, 1964), (1965, 1965), (1966, 1966), (1967, 1967), (1968, 1968), (1969, 1969), (1970, 1970), (1971, 1971), (1972, 1972), (1973, 1973), (1974, 1974), (1975, 1975), (1976, 1976), (1977, 1977), (1978, 1978), (1979, 1979), (1980, 1980), (1981, 1981), (1982, 1982), (1983, 1983), (1984, 1984), (1985, 1985), (1986, 1986), (1987, 1987), (1988, 1988), (1989, 1989), (1990, 1990), (1991, 1991), (1992, 1992), (1993, 1993), (1994, 1994), (1995, 1995), (1996, 1996), (1997, 1997), (1998, 1998), (1999, 1999), (2000, 2000), (2001, 2001), (2002, 2002), (2003, 2003), (2004, 2004), (2005, 2005), (2006, 2006), (2007, 2007), (2008, 2008), (2009, 2009), (2010, 2010), (2011, 2011), (2012, 2012), (2013, 2013), (2014, 2014), (2015, 2015), (2016, 2016), (2017, 2017), (2018, 2018), (2019, 2019), (2020, 2020), (2021, 2021), (2022, 2022), (2023, 2023), (2024, 2024)]
name=models.CharField(max_length=256,verbose_name='Название')
year=models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES,verbose_name='Год')
author=models.CharField(max_length=120,verbose_name='Автор')
publishing_house=models.CharField(max_length=120,verbose_name='Издательство')
numbers=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='ИН')
qr_code = models.ImageField()



def __str__(self):
   return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Художественная литература'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Художественная литература'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать в соответствии с примером.
